# How to access an element with two classes divided by space and drop all the others (nokogiri, ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm writing a parser and want to take element only with class name "row1 processed"

```
  <tbody class = "processed"> some data1 </tbody> 
  <tbody class = "row1 props processed"> some data2 </tbody> 
  <tbody class = "row1 processed"> some data3 </tbody>
```

via gem nokogiri.

I can do it for row1, processed, props; but I need only "row1 processed"

```
   test =  el.css('tbody.row1')
   test =  el.css('tbody.processed')
```

How can i do this?

I'm using ruby on rails 5.2.2

## Update

When I typed el.css('tbody.row1.props') it displayed informaton from this
element

```
 <tbody class = "row1 props processed"> some data2 </tbody>
```

but when I added "processed" class then I got nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Separate multiple classes with dots:

```
el.css('tbody.row1.processed')
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the Ruby developers Slack channel, the underlying issue here is that Nokogiri can only access the initially loaded HTML from the page (what you see when you click View Source), before it has been modified by JavaScript. This is why it's not accessible in Nokogiri, since at this point the `processed` class hasn't been loaded. The other answer here works if the HTML is available on page load.

If you need to modify a page after it has been modified by JavaScript, you have two choices: either use JavaScript to access newly-modified DOM elements, or rethink how you parse the web page to get what you want.